# Odds of a members draw going off

Tags: probability

Here's a silly question that's dividing a few of the people at work and we can't seem to reach a consensus:

"Last night at the pub there was a members draw that had to go off i.e. they would keep drawing numbers at random from the list of members until a member who was present at the pub was drawn.

There are 6000 members total, but there were only 500 members present.

What are the odds of me winning (I am present and am a member)?

Note: Each random draw is taken from the 6000 members total i.e. a member could conceivably be drawn out more than once."

Comment: 1 person said 1 in 500,  another says 1 in 6000 and another said 1 in 12 (500 in 6000).

Comment: I am impressed that someone got it right. The general intuition about probability tends to be not very good.

Comment: I'm definitely one of those people!  I think that's why we're having a hard time agreeing on an answer at work.  Everyone has a different "logic" that they use to justify their result.

Comment: This is the main reason casinos, lotteries, get rich.

Comment: Just as a supplement to the correct answer already given: $1$ in $6000$ is the chance that a specified person (whether present or not) is drawn from a single draw, and $1$ in $12$ is the chance that some person present (but not a specified person) is drawn from a single draw.  Your colleagues would seem to be giving the right answers to the wrong questions.  This is not uncommon with probability questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 100% chance someone at the event wins, so we can ignore the other non-present members for now.

$1/500$ is the chance you win, which is 1 to 499 odds. This is because there are 500 members and 1 of "you".

This is because they keep drawing until they get the number of someone there, so they have to draw the number of someone there *eventually*. How long is the average "eventually"? Now that's a good question.

For that we note that there is a $p={{6000-500} \over {6000}}=91.6...%$ chance of a draw calling on someone not present. In that very likely case the draw has to be redone. But, as the probability that three draws are needed is $p^3=0.77..%$. So, needing 100 draws is *less* likely than needing 5.

WIP

Comment: Sorry, I worded the question a bit poorly there!  I've edited to say what are the odds of me winning.

Comment: @ClintO that's in my answer as well.

Comment: By the way, the mean number of draws until someone present has her/his name called is $\frac{6000}{500}$.